# YouTube video id change after some time

Tags: javascript, php, video, youtube, embed

I embed YouTube live Video in my site with the help of its id.
It was working fine.
But after sometime i noticed the channel's id has been changed.
Is there any solution that i can keep Live Video id valid although it goes to changed?
This time a Live channel have id **vic1y557xRU** but before some days it's id was like **AnX1y831yVq**

Answer (score 1):

use youtube.com/user/xxx/live path instead of video id.

for example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA9UZF-SZoQ is livestream video of Nasa and its working now but after some time video id will expire.

but

https://www.youtube.com/user/NASAtelevision/live is always working :)

Comment: How do you get the user id? In your example, where did you find: NASAtelevision? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to change it every time when channel id changes. Channel current id doesn't depends on past id or their is no formula which can make relation.